# Как получить ссылку на view?

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Во view можно изменить ссылку, как сделать так чтобы это изменение не влияло на ссылки которые уже есть в шаблонх?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать следующий код

```
use \Drupal\Core\Url;

$url = Url::fromRoute('view.VIEW_MACHINE_NAME.PAGE_MACHINENAME');
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

А если это нужно в темплейте Twig тогда

```
{{ path('view.VIEW_MACHINE_NAME.PAGE_MACHINENAME') }}
```

Более подробно можно глянуть здесь

[Drupal 8 Views: How to formulate the route name](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/drupal-8-views-how-formulate-route-name)